# Getting common tuple elements

Tags: python

How can I turn this:

```
(("and", "dog"), ("a", "dog"))
```

Into this:

```
("and", "dog", "a")
```

Which means getting the common element `"dog"` only once.

Comment: Is ordering important? If not, just use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> tuple(set(("and", "dog")) | set(("a", "dog")))
('and', 'a', 'dog')
```

Or, generally:

```
import operator
tuple(reduce(operator.__or__, map(set, mytuples)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could cast it as a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

```
diff = (set(("a","dog")) - set(("and","dog")))
result = list(("and","dog")) + list((diff))
print(result)  #['and', 'dog', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

If order doesn't matter:

```
>>> tuple(set.union(*map(set, tuples)))
('and', 'a', 'dog')
```

If order does matter:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> tuple(elem for tupl in tuples for elem in tupl
          if elem not in seen and not seen.add(elem))
('and', 'dog', 'a')
```